# AngularJS nested scopes and altering $parent scope variables

Tags: javascript, angularjs, scope

Apologies if this has been asked before, I couldn't find anything on SO and I'm hoping for some clarification ( or a nice neat trick )

Given

```
<div ng-controller="Parent"> 
    <div ng-controller="Child">
        //child manipulation of parent scope object
    </div>
</div>
```

Parent sets json object so it is available to multiple child scopes -

```
$scope.persistentData = getAJSONObject();
```

A child scope wants to do some calculations and update a key of the local json object it has  inherited from the parent -

```
doCalculations( $scope.persistentData.keyIWantToAlter )
```

Do I need to explicitly assign the parent scope to the result of the calculation function in the child (shown below) or is there a way that I can propogate the changes to the parent scope by just using the child's inherited scope objects?

```
$parent.$scope.$persistentData.keyIWantToAlter = 
    doCalculations( $scope.persistentData.keyIWantToAlter)
```

Comment: Please consider rewording, its currently really hard to follow what you are asking.

Comment: Hopefully I haven't made it worse

Comment: It is clearer.. is `getAJSONObject` async ?

Comment: It is async but has been provided via resolve so it should not be treated as such once the parent scope has initialized

Comment: Last ? is inside of `doCalculations` are you do anything like `$scope.persistentData = ...`

Comment: No I'm not currently, I was hoping to avoid that to keep the code maintainable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't see any problems with the blurb you gave you will need to give us more.  I can caution you about trying to "share" nested objects on scope.

[This fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ncapito/m53gf/) illustrates what happens if you are in the child and you "overwrite" the reference. The `json2` shows that these start off the same, but I overwrite the reference in the child scope and now the variables are detached.

I think you are experiencing a similar issue but can't prove it until you provide more info.

```
<div ng-controller="ParentCtrl">
  Hello, {{json2}}!
    <div ng-controller="ChildCtrl">
          Hello, {{json2}}!
    </div>
</div>



function ParentCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.json2 = {
         child:{
            name: 'parent'
        }
    }

}

function ChildCtrl($scope, $timeout) {

    $scope.json2 = {
         child:{
            name: 'child'
        }
    }

    $timeout(function(){
         $scope.json2.child.name= 'nick';
     },5000);
}
```

Comment: Thanks it was indeed a silly overwrite I hadn't spotted which leads me to think that even though the explicit $parent references are ugly they may be safer in the long run

Comment: Use services ;)  you can run into all kinds of issues when you rely on nested scopes.

Comment: Thanks I must look into that, would you provide the service to the parent controller or should I be thinking entirely outside controllers ?